# What is the name of that quick popup text at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android

I'm searching for the term of that little text that just pops up for a second at the bottom of a screen (like the one that appears if you tap a couple of times on the build number in the Prefrences). I only found complex Dialogs and messages.
Is it possible to create one of these by yourself in an app?

Thanks!

[image: I mean the white text on dark background at the bottom]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This message is called `Toast`.

Example:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

- `this` is the context.
- The second parameter is your message.
- The third parameter is the toast duration.

Comment: I want to add that "this" is the app context and Toast.makeText can only be called from the UI Thread, otherwise you will get a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 6):

This pop-up is called [a `Toast`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Answer (score 2):

That is `Toast` message

you can create it by

```
Toast.makeText(this, "this is my Toast message! :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```